# Logback beagle does not work under Spring tool suite

Tags: eclipse-plugin, logback, spring-tool-suite

I have STS 3.6.3 running on 64bit windows 7, java 1.8u25. According to the http://logback.qos.ch/beagle/index.html I have installed the following plugins:

- Logback Beagle Feature   1.1.4.201209042005
- Logback Feature  1.0.7
- Nebula Grid Feature  1.0.0.201412230843
- SLF4J Feature    1.6.6

Unfortunatelly the Beagle window does not show up and the following error is written in the STS log: http://pastebin.com/YpL00TZ3

Can you help ?

Comment: Can anybody can help me ? Or at least provide some point where to ask ?

Comment: This is a problem with conflicting dependencies among those plugins and the existing ones, especially with multiple versions of the slf4j.api plugin. I would recommend to not install the slf4j plugin to avoid having this plugin installed in multiple versions at the same time. Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to clean up conflicting SLF4J libraries in eclipse, then modify the manifest of the Beagle jar to depend on the version of SLF4J already in eclipse.

In spite of the documentation, you need to remove the Logback Feature and SLF4J Feature from Eclipse (They can be removed via Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details > Install Software).  You should only have "Nebula Grid Feature" and "Logback Beagle Feature" installed for Beagle.

Then you need to browse to your eclipse/plugins folder and open 'ch.qos.logback.beagle_1.1.4.201209042005.jar' in your favorite zip tool, then edit `WEB-INF/MANIFEST.MF' to change the text`slf4j.api;bundle-version="1.6.6"`to`org.slf4j.api;bundle-version="1.7.2"`.  Make sure to save the updated file back in the jar.

Finally, restart eclipse from the command line using `eclipse.exe -clean`.

Source:  The discussion [here](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback-beagle/issues/2) and commit [here](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback-beagle/commit/d7d8f51a96ddffa6c64c7f99fd8f5d84a6f727d8).